# withCriteria "or" like by property of other table

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have this:

```
results = Quotation.withCriteria {
    resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
            createAlias("client","cte")
            createAlias("client.assessor","asr")
        or{
            ilike("asr.name", "%${params.find}%") 
            ilike("cte.name", "%${params.find}%")
        }
        projections {   
             groupProperty "id","id"
             groupProperty "cte.name", "client"
             groupProperty "asr.name", "employee"
        }
}
```

but return empty, I think it's by associations (client and client.assessor), I need to search by customer name or assessor name but this is a property from other table/obj.

Answer (score 0):

Change your createAlias to

```
def results = Quotation.withCriteria {
    resultTransformer CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP
    createAlias "client","cte"
    createAlias "cte.assessor","asr" /* <--- HERE ^^ */

    or {
        ilike "asr.name", "%${params.find}%" 
        ilike "cte.name", "%${params.find}%"
    }
    projections {   
         groupProperty "id","id"
         groupProperty "cte.name", "client"
         groupProperty "asr.name", "employee"
    }
}
```

Comment: And prettify your code removing all these parenthesis. I mean, that's one good reason we should like groovy/Grails! (;